# .NET Task.Run safe to use due to AppRecycle?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am reading a lot about AppRecycling, which bothers me since a long time. I do not understand, I often read that if you use Task.Run that it is not safe to use, because it can be recycled ?

Can someone explain me, what this AppRecycle does and when I use Task.Run, am I safe to say that this Task will be executed or is it possible that the Recycle process cancels this Task?

I am also talking about a .NET Core WebApi, don't know if this matters or not.

What I need is an API that responds immediatly to the user, but launches a "Process", using Task.Run to contact some APIs and do some calculation "in the background".

Many thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not happening when using a Docker container. As @Martheen already mentioned, there is no recycling going on inside Docker.